# Extending the plot from ggplot for forecast

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to forecast revenue levels in a particular date in the future. What I did is to apply a smoothing curve in my plot. The code is this

```
ggplot(timeseries, aes(x=Weekstarting, y=PHCumm))+
geom_line()+
stat_smooth(method = glm, fullrange =TRUE, formula= y~poly(x,5))
```

I tried to get smart and add this little snippet at the end
    xlim=c(as.POSIXct('2017-01-01 00:00:00', format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
+          as.POSIXct('2017-07-01 00:00:00', format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

and I  get the error.

**Error in unclass(e2) : cannot unclass an environment**

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: What  exactly were you trying to do with that?

Comment: I just simply want to extend the x-axis until Jul 2017 so I can see how the model behaves.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is `scale_x_date` (or `scale_x_datetime`, depending on your data):

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(42)

# sample data
timeseries <- data_frame(
    Weekstarting = 
        seq.Date(
            from = as.Date("2017-01-02"),
            by = "week",
            length.out = 250
        ),
    PHCumm = cumsum(rnorm(250))
    )

timeseries %>% ggplot(aes(x = Weekstarting, y = PHCumm)) +
    geom_line() +
    stat_smooth(method = glm, fullrange =TRUE, formula= y~poly(x,5)) +
    scale_x_date(limits = c(as.Date("2017-01-02"), as.Date("2022-06-02")))
```

[image]